# I can edit Meta privilege wikis even though I don't have 20K rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, community-wiki, privileges

I was looking through the [privilege wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) for trusted users, and read at the bottom:

> Meta Stack Overflow Specific: Along with the tag-wiki edit privilege, you also get the privilege to edit the Privileges entries.

I noticed something odd, though: I have the "edit wiki" link.

[image: edit wiki link picture]

When I click it, it takes me to the wiki edit page.

[image: edit wiki page]

After being asked to test the edit, I performed [this edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66738/18) (which has now been rolled back) without review.

Comment: Doesn't that just submit it for review?

Comment: @Bart I guess so otherwise it is a bug since I have access too.  I guess 20k users can edit it without being reviewed.

Comment: @Bart I'm not sure. It's not a tag wiki, though it may go into review anyway.

Comment: Try it. Worst case we roll it back.

Comment: @Bart Edit was submitted without review.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Oh my god, you submitted it? Who told you to do...ah...wait.

Comment: Rolled back the change ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the Wiki entry appears to be wrong.

On MSO (and MSO alone), privilege wiki pages are editable by +1000 rep users.

Since these are pages that are wiki and have revisions, we can always rollback/correct them.

When we do roll out the updates to the rest of the network, we do check them...

Comment: Editable without review? Or just editable?

Comment: Interesting. Any particular reason it is that way?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi - They are seen as a community effort and they only effect one site, Meta.

Comment: @Bart - Without review.

Comment: Do you "roll out the updates" on some regular interval? Per request?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Seems to be fairly ad-hoc. When someone notices ;)